# ¿Puedo seleccionar que validaciones de una propiedad de una clase usar segun que vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
//Propiedad de la clase "Usuario" con sus respectivas validaciones
[ValidateDNIRepetit(ErrorMessage = "El correo ya existe")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo no puede estar vacio")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "No es una dirección de correo válida")]
public string Email { get; set; }  

//Implementación de la propiedad de dicha clase en cualquier vista Razor, pues la uso en varias
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
 </div>
```

¿Tengo alguna manera de elegir en una vista en concreto cual de las 3 validaciones de la propiedad usar? Pues en uno de los formularios no necesito la validación "ValidateDNIRepetit", pero las otras 2 si.
Gracias

Comment: En las 3 vistas usas el mismo modelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando solo Asp.Net MVC la forma correcta sería crear una clase `Model` para cada view dependiendo de cual validación quieres aplicar.

O sea tendrías dos clases de modelo y cada action del controller asigna a la view según la validación que se requiere.

```
public class UsuarioModelCreate{

    [ValidateDNIRepetit(ErrorMessage = "El correo ya existe")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo no puede estar vacio")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "No es una dirección de correo válida")]
    public string Email { get; set; }  

}

public class UsuarioModelEdit{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo no puede estar vacio")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "No es una dirección de correo válida")]
    public string Email { get; set; }  

}


public class xxController: Controller{

    public ActionResult Create(){

        UsuarioModelCreate model = new UsuarioModelCreate();

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(){

        UsuarioModelEdit model = new UsuarioModelEdit();

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: siempre dándole en el clavo @Leandro!

Comment: Tengo una duda, si "duplico la clase" par hacer los viewmodels o parte de la clase en otras clases luego tengo que hacer los DAL otra vez repetidos verdad? No hay otra manera de simplemente anular validaciones en ciertas vistas?

Comment: las clases que usas para la view no deberias usarlos en la persistencias, deberias ser entidades diferentes que mapeas usando automapper http://automapper.org/  recuerda que tambien puedes usar herencia en las clases de la view, de esta forma puedes definir propiedades comunes y solo definir la que valida diferentes